# How do I remove "X-TMASE-MatchedRID" key/value using "egrep -v"?

Tags: linux, grep

My file contains something like the below:

```
X-TM-AS-Product-Ver: IMSVA-8.2.0.1391-8.0.0.1202-22662.005
X-TM-AS-Result: No--0.364-7.0-31-10
X-imss-scan-details: No--0.364-7.0-31-10
X-TMASE-Version: IMSVA-8.2.0.1391-8.0.1202-22662.005
X-TMASE-Result: 10--0.363600-5.000000
X-TMASE-MatchedRID: 40jyuBT4FtykMGOaBzW2QbxygpRxo469FspPdEyOR1qJNv6smPBGj5g3
        9Rgsjteo4vM1YF6AJbZcLc3sLtjOty5V0GTrwsKpl6V6bOpOzUAdzA5USlz33EYWGTXfmDJJ3Qf
    wsVk0UbuGrPnef/I+eo9h73qb6JgVCR2fClyPE+EPh2lMKov3fdtvzshqXylpWZGeMhmJ7ScqBW
    z6M5VHW/fngY5M/1HkzhvqqZL61o+ZdBoyruxjzQ==

This is my real text! I need to extract this line!
```

The existing code, written in the past by someone else, executes the below line:

```
cat $my_file | egrep -v "^(X-TM-AS)" 
             | egrep -v "X-imss-scan-details"
```

supposedly to remove all those key value lines which start with "X-".

The above piece of code has been working fine up until today because keys starting with `X-TMASE` has never been among the keys in the past. It has started to appear in the files today, and therefore it has caused the code to fail in extraction of the useful data.

Among the newly added keys, it seems to me that `X-TMASE-MatchedRID` is the one creating the headache for us, as it has a value which spans multiple lines:

```
X-TMASE-MatchedRID: 40jyuBT4FtykMGOaBzW2QbxygpRxo469FspPdEyOR1qJNv6smPBGj5g3
        9Rgsjteo4vM1YF6AJbZcLc3sLtjOty5V0GTrwsKpl6V6bOpOzUAdzA5USlz33EYWGTXfmDJJ3Qf
    wsVk0UbuGrPnef/I+eo9h73qb6JgVCR2fClyPE+EPh2lMKov3fdtvzshqXylpWZGeMhmJ7ScqBW
    z6M5VHW/fngY5M/1HkzhvqqZL61o+ZdBoyruxjzQ==
```

Initially I tried the below:

```
cat $my_file | egrep -v "^(X-TM-AS)" 
             | egrep -v "X-imss-scan-details"
             | egrep -v "^(X-TMASE-)"
```

But it didn't work. It didn't completely eliminate the value for `X-TMASE-MatchedRID`:

```
9Rgsjteo4vM1YF6AJbZcLc3sLtjOty5V0GTrwsKpl6V6bOpOzUAdzA5USlz33EYWGTXfmDJJ3Qf
    wsVk0UbuGrPnef/I+eo9h73qb6JgVCR2fClyPE+EPh2lMKov3fdtvzshqXylpWZGeMhmJ7ScqBW
    z6M5VHW/fngY5M/1HkzhvqqZL61o+ZdBoyruxjzQ==

This is my real text! I need to extract this line!
```

I wanted the output to be:

```
This is my real text! I need to extract this line!
```

That is, I don't want any metadata to be seen in the output.

Any idea how that can be achieved using egrep or any equivalent command?

Comment: perhaps filter out all lines starting with `X-` or starting with space? `grep -vE '^X-|^ ' `

Comment: @Sundeep well, I am worried that the text itself might start with spaces. The solution which mkj provided has actually worked. So, I am going to mark that one as accepted. Thanks for your comment anyway! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove the first paragraph some other command is better, for example `sed`

```
sed '1,/^$/ d' "$my_file"
```